# Error running GenomicVis vcf.venn(vcf.files, 'GRCh38', sample.names)

Tags: r

I am trying to draw venn diagrams with a GenomicVis package (R).

```
library(GenomicVis)
```

It is loaded with a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: replacing previous import ‘IRanges::shift’ by ‘data.table::shift’ when loading ‘GenomicVis’ 
2: replacing previous import ‘S4Vectors::second’ by ‘data.table::second’ when loading ‘GenomicVis’ 
3: replacing previous import ‘S4Vectors::first’ by ‘data.table::first’ when loading ‘GenomicVis’ 

f2 <- system.file("extdata", "S038_10_wes_S43.vcf", package ="GenomicVis")
f1 <- system.file("extdata", "S038_1_wes_S25.vcf.gz",package = "GenomicVis")
vcf.files <- c(f1, f2)
sample.names <- c('Sample 1','Sample 10') 
v <- vcf.venn(vcf.files, 'GRCh38', sample.names)
```

But then this Error comes up, no clue how to solve it:

```
Error in rowData(read.vcf(f, genome, ...)) : 
 could not find function "rowData
```

I also think that the problem is reading my vcf files as calling f1 or f2 results in [1] "", however when I open them with cat I can see vcf table as it is. The first line is ##fileformat=VCFv4.2. I tried using fullpath or running R from this folder and still the file was not loaded as system file is used only for loading example files from a package.

Loading file with a readVcf('S038_10_wes_043.vcf', 'hg38') worked well.

Comment: Hi @EkatSim this might be enough for a member to trouble-shoot, however this could be a result of your input format. You might need to supply more details. Personally, I'd like to peer into f1 and f2 objects to see what is there.